# powershell does not fire "System.Reflection.Assembly.Load" in the event receiver

Tags: powershell, event-receivers

There is a problem with Enable-SPFeature command in case of having an event receiver in the feature. Feature Activated event is not fired. 
If I enable the feature manually everything works well.
So, there is a workaround for this :

[workaroud](https://mypowershell.webnode.sk/news/activate-feature-with-event-receiver-by-powershell/)

In my case, the feature is scope: WEB

```
$web= Get-SPWeb -Site https://aaa.com

        $feature = Get-SPFeature "Guid" 
            if($feature)
            {
                $featureId = $feature.Id;
                $site = Get-SPSite $site.Url
                if(-not $web.Features[$featureId])
                {
                    $web.Features.Add($featureId);
                }
            }
```

error:

> Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or
>   assembly 'App_GlobalResources' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified."

So any idea how can I fire the event receiver.

event receiver:

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
            {
 //get ressource value 
            ResourceManager MyResourceClass = new ResourceManager("Resources.MySite.Global", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
            string title= MyResourceClass.GetString("UserControl_Message_Title");
            string Message = MyResourceClass.GetString("UserControl_Message_Description");

using (SPWeb oWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
                {
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                      {
                          SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["splist"];

                          SPListItem oListItem = oList.Items.Add();
                          oListItem["Title"] = title;
                          oListItem["Message"] = msg;

                          oListItem.Update();

                      });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your feature assembly GACed? If not, make sure the feature assembly is located someplace where powershell can find it.

Comment: at the feature properties the "receiver Assembly :$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" already, any idea how can i added, ow can i make powershell know it ?

Comment: Before enabling the feature, GAC the dll App_GlobalResources and then execute the powershell command

Comment: the wsp is installed whith "-GACDeployment" , i checked the feature under the templates/feature , i found it. but when i nuild the solution i only found dll of wsp and not dll App_GlobalResources

Comment: Does your code uses httpcontext?? Because when you deploy from UI, httpcontext will be there but the same will not be available in powershell activation

Comment: Usually this happens if you have feature activated event receiver and use http context in code somehow (accessing to SPContext.Current or creating web part, that might use internally Http context). When you activate your feature through UI, Http context is not null and all may work as expected, but when activating through PS or stsadm Http context is null and this may lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: I update the question and the code , because i figure out that powershell does not fire "System.Reflection.Assembly.Load" in the event receiver , any idea how can i make it works

Comment: Error is very clear, your powershell command is trying to find the dll App_GlobalResources, it's not able.to find it, so we are getting that error. Solution will be GAC the  App_GlobalResources dll and execute your powershell command.

Comment: the "App_GlobalResources" is a module filled whith ressource file. so I tried to call dll of the hole wsp, and call it [Environment]::Is64BitProcess
 [reflection.assembly]::LoadFrom('E:\DEV\release13\MySite.dll')
 [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("App_GlobalResources"), and i dosent work

Comment: but where i can find the App_GlobalResources.dll in ly SPProject, the bin folder dosent have it

Comment: It will not be in your sp solution, search in the c drive in SharePoint server